# Getting an Error: access denied for Node.js with mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm trying to get a node.js app that uses mysql to work. I run sudo node app.js and I get this error:

```
Express server listening on port 80 in development mode

events.js:48
        throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
                       ^
Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at cmd.process_packet (/Users/.../Documents/Code/.../node_modules/mysql-native/lib/mysql-native/command.js:35:15)
    at SocketClient.dispatch_packet (/Users/.../Documents/Code/.../node_modules/mysql-native/lib/mysql-native/socketclient.js:105:32)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/.../Documents/Code/.../node_modules/mysql-native/lib/mysql-native/socketclient.js:59:18)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:67:17)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:362:31)
```

I set up a secure user and password for mysql but it's not asking me for a password besides one for sudo. I'm a beginner with both node.js and especially mysql so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you application come with a config file that you had to edit to give it permissions? Are you running the application as `root`?

Comment: Where would I find the config file? I'm not sure what root would be, sorry.

Comment: Presumably you had to configure _something_ to tell the application which server and port or socket to use to connect to MySQL; that configuration would also include a username and password. `root` is the superuser account, with uid `0`. Are you running as `root` when you start the application?

Comment: In the client.js file, it says the user is root and the password is null so I think yes.

Comment: Once the system software allows you to do so, would you add that as an answer for the future? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I contacted someone who had done this before and he helped me through it. Basically I connected to mysql with mysql -u root -p, entered in my password, created the database and put use that database and entered in all the database information. Then in api.js under db.auth, in parenthesis I put the database name, my username and the password, each as strings separated by commas. In a separate terminal tab I then ran the node.js application and it worked.